# Previous Month based on SYSDATE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table called PRTIME with a date field called TR_DATE.  Based on the SYSDATE, I need to query the PRTIME table for the month prior to SYSDATE.

In SQL Server I would do the following:

```
select * from PRTIME
WHERE datepart(month,TR_DATE) = datepart(month,dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
and datepart(year,TR_DATE) = datepart(year,dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
```

How would I do this in Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just do

```
WHERE tr_date >= trunc( add_months( sysdate, -1 ), 'MM' )
  AND tr_date <  trunc( sysdate, 'MM' )
```

Comment: Interesting - I'll have to read up on the trunc function.  This will work perfectly for me.  Thanks Justin!